# Get patents data data only child has empty data in relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, parent-child, is-empty

I have a collection like the below. I need to fetch those users, whom does not uploaded documents. Now from the relationship, How can I fetch this?

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 8
            [referred_by] => 
            ........          

            [user_documents] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [user_id] => 9
            [referred_by] => 
            [reference_id] => NM1100008
            .......                    

            [user_documents] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [customer_id] => 3
                    [doc_type] => 1
                    [document] => N8xFORsPpkTayTQ9Ihyz0ly7QM62TJHxvHhSFQSN.png
                    [admin_comment] => 
                    [approve_status] => approve
                    [other_gov_id] => 
                    [doc_no] => 1
                    [created_at] => 2020-04-04 12:39:12
                    [updated_at] => 2020-04-06 13:57:01
                    [deleted_at] => 
                )

        )
```

I want to get rows only when **user_documents is empty.**. To get those users who does not uploaded documents to the system.

```
[user_documents] =>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use laravel [querying-relationship-absence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

```
$users= User::doesntHave('user_documents')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have setup your relations, something like this should work:

```php
User::doesntHave('documents')->get();
```